# Is there a way to show safe and performing image?

Tags: reactjs, performance

I have a react project. One application is api project and another project is identity server. Api project protected with bearer token by identity server.

Api project have a function in FilesController.  This function return image url. This function should need beraer token in Authorization header for execute.

This function is below

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/file/{types}/{param1}")]
public string Files(string types, string param1)
{
    return _fileService.GetDefaultLogoPath((Model.Enum.LogoType)logoType);
}
```

I have a react component to show api return url. This component is below

```
public componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchImage();
}
fetchImage = () => {
    fetch(this.props.imageUrl, {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + 'AccessToken',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        }
    }).then((response: any) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
            return response.text();
        } else {
            throw(new Error(response.statusCode));
        }
    }).then(imageUrl => {
        if (this.props.preventCaching) {
            imageUrl += (imageUrl.indexOf('?') > 0 ? '&' : '?') + '_rnd=' + Date.now();
        }
        this.setState({ source: imageUrl });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        _logger.error('in componentDidMount -> image could not be loaded -> ' + this.props.imageUrl, err);
        this.setState({ source: _common.GetDefaultImages(this.props.imgType ? '' : this.props.imgType as string) });
    });
}
onClick = (evt: any) => {
    if (typeof this.props.onClick === 'function') {
        this.props.onClick(evt);
    }
}

public render() {
    return <img
        style={this.props.style}
        src={this.state.source}
        className={this.props.class}
        width={this.props.width}
        height={this.props.height}
        onError={typeof this.props.onError === 'function' ? this.props.onError :     _common.OnErrorImageSrc }
        data-imgtype={this._imgType}
        onClick={this.onClick}
    />;
}
```

This component adds bearer token for api url. This code is work true, but more api call for more image in the page. For example 100 image.

Is there a way to show safe and performing image ?

Comment: Use cookies to store your token, then you don't have to worry about adding it as a header every time.

Comment: I save token to local storage, but must to every request add bearer token.  it's not performing @JMadelaine

Comment: Don't save token to local storage, it's not secure. https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/guides/store-tokens#don-t-store-tokens-in-local-storage

Comment: Thank you. I will careful this.